# What is exactly mean by retaining metadata in S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

While studying about S3 Single Region Replication ,I came across the point Replicate while retaining object metadata.
Can someone explain what's exactly mean by metadata retention and how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Replicating Objects User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html):

> Replicate objects while retaining metadata — You can use replication to make copies of your objects that retain all metadata, such as the original object creation time and version IDs. This capability is important if you need to ensure that your replica is identical to the source object.

So, if you want an exact replica of the data *and* metadata, then you can do so. If you only want the data replicated, then that's the default behavior.